# How to get week days between two different dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Here I need a way to find out the weekdays between two dates. If I supply two dates like '2014-08-28' and '2014-08-30', it should return `['Friday','Saturday']`.

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

How can I use `.getDay()`?

Comment: How about if you supply 2013-08-28 and 2014-08-30? Should it return an array with 367 items?

Comment: But there is only one day **between** 28 and 30 August. ;-) You seem to already know how to convert *date.getDay* to a day name, so just increment the early date in steps and get the name of each day, until you reach the last date.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez–I was commenting on the OP, hence no @….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to write a few functions and most importantly, use Date.parse to conver the date to ms and do math between dates. A solution is the following. See jsFiddle for working code. *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xrj6250/2/)*

```
var days = 3;
var msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;


var nextDay = function ( day , dayAfter ) {
    return Date.parse(day) + (msPerDay*dayAfter);
}

var daysBetween = function ( from, to ) {
  return ((Date.parse(to) - Date.parse(from))/msPerDay) - 1 ;
}


var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date( nextDay( d1, days ));

var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";


var getInbetweenWeekdays = function () {
   var weekDays = [];
   for (var i = 0 ; i < daysBetween( d1, d2 ); i++ ) {
       weekDays.push(weekday[new Date( nextDay( d1, i + 1 ) ).getDay()]);
   }

   return weekDays;
}



alert(getInbetweenWeekdays());
```

Elaborate it a little, add proper getter setters and you'll be fine, but you get the drift.

Comment: In general you will recognise a functional approach. Javascript is really good at it.